# Unable to create a project in Django

Tags: django

I tried both methods but I am unable to understand what's wrong, I'm using `django 1.11.7`, it was working a few months ago. I only have one python version installed.

**I get this system message:**

> C:\WINDOWS\system32>django-admin.py startproject wisdompets
>
> Unable to create process using 'c:\program files\python36\python.exe
>   "C:\Program Files\Python36\Scripts\django-admin.py"  startprojects
>   wisdompets'
>
> C:\WINDOWS\system32>django-admin startproject test_project

**Fatal error in launcher: Unable to create process using '"'**

Answer (score 1):

Did you activate your virtual environment where Django was installed?

Maybe you had installed Django in a virtual environment and your system might not have Django.

Answer (score 0):

It should be :
django-admin startproject projectname

For doubts refer here: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I used both django-admin and django-admin.py as reflected in my original post, it didn't work.

Comment: where have you initialised your project?Can you go and try to startproject somewhere else like in D folder and run django-admin startproject projectname

Answer (score 0):

This was not the most elegant walkaround but I managed to fix it by uninstalling both python and django then reinstalling them.